# QMetaObject::invokeMethod returns true, but method is never called

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt, multithreading

I'm trying to run a method on the GUI thread using QMetaObject::invokeMethod, which returns true. But, if I use Qt::QueuedConnection my method never gets called (even if invokeMethod returns true).

This is what I'm using:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "draw_widgets", Qt::QueuedConnection)
```

I don't get any error messages or anything...
If I use Qt::AutoConnection or Qt::DirectConnection the method does get called, but from the same thread of course. Not from the GUI thread, which is what I need.

draw_widgets is a public slot of type void draw_widgets()
and my class inherits QObject and uses the Q_OBJECT macro as well.

I would appreciate any help on this, or on how to check why the method is not being called.

Thanks.

Comment: I have a similar situation: I have a class that inherits from QObject and uses `Q_OBJECT`. The instance of this class is created in the main loop. Then, while executing a method of the same class in the main loop, I call `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "hideListsSlot", Qt::QueuedConnection);`, where `void hideListsSlot()` is a public slot of the class. The slot is never invoked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "true" is telling you the message was successfully queued.  That doesn't mean the queued message was ever processed...

Let us say your program has 10 threads (Thread1-Thread10).  You queue a message from Thread7.  Which thread will it be queued to?  And when will items on this queue be processed?

The answer is that every `QObject` has something called [Thread Affinity](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread-affinity), and this is the thread where a queued slot will be run. The default affinity is to the thread where the object was created (but you can change it with [`QObject::moveToThread()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread).)

If you want to queue something to the GUI thread, then the object specified by your `this` pointer should have the GUI thread's affinity. You can check this with the [`QObject::thread()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread) method.

But in any case, no matter what thread you queue to... you must have some kind of message pump running on that thread.  Look at for instance [`QThread::exec()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#exec). If your thread affinity is to the GUI then presumably this is already the case because you are running the app's exec.

*(As a sidenote, direct calls to `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` are usually unnecessary.  You can create a signal and tie it to a slot, then emit the signal in lieu of the invoke.)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I didn't know about Thread Affinity. Changing the affinity of the object to the GUI thread solved the problem.

Comment: @HostileFork opposite sidenote, if you have too many slots, it will be created signals as same as slots, so in this case it is fair enough to use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "slot 1 ... n", Qt::QueuedConnection)`.

Comment: @HostileFork opposite sidenote continue, the `invokeMethod` call shoud be palced in slot inside condition check `if (QThread::currentThread() != thread())`. by this way, clients can call slots direclty.